# Oracle PLSQL, select in DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to usue select query in DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS but the code I wrote returns an error.

```
EXECUTE DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS((select sys_context( 'userenv','current_schema') from dual));
```

The query: select sys_context( 'userenv','current_schema') from dual; returns the schema name.

And this is my error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
BEGIN DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS((select sys_context( 'userenv','current_schema') from dual)); END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 39:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
   sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
   date <a string literal with character set specification>
   <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
   <alternatywnie oznaczany literał napisowy ze specyfikacją zestawu znaków>
   <alternatywn
ORA-06550: line 1, column 96:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

   . , @ ; for <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> group having intersect
   minus order partition start subpartition union where connect

06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: Why not `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS(USER);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are too close. No need to use `SELECT .. FROM DUAL`

Use the following code:

```
EXECUTE DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS(sys_context( 'userenv','current_schema'));
```

Cheers!!